# ASP.NET ValidationMessage validate false my double number

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, validation

I am using NET MVC, EF 6, Entity Data Model to build a site.This page is "Create Sach
In the DB, Table `Sach`, which have fields: `Dai`, `Rong`, `Cao` as float. When running it's allow only int input
 [image]

[image: EF generated class:]

But when debug, I enter 1.2 and 1,2, both value are not valid, though they are double!
[image]

Comment: What is the server culture (it may expect `,` (comma) as the decimal separator

Comment: According to this image, `1,2` (with the comma) is indeed valid.

Comment: I tried bot comma and dot separately, both of them are invalid, I included both of them in the example only to show that they didn't work either

Comment: Look at your own image - there is no validation error when you enter `1,2` in the textbox for `Rong` - its not invalid!

Comment: OMG! Sorry :) My mistake

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify server culture. Easiest way to do this:

```
<system.web>
  <globalization culture="auto" uiCulture="auto" />
</system.web>
```

Auto will use user's OS culture to process current request. You can use "en-US" or any other culture code here.